# Switch Amazon EC2 instance from small to large, reusing block device

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created a small Amazon EC2 instance like this:

```
ec2-run-instances --group default --block-device-mapping "/dev/sda1=:16:off" \
  --instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior stop ami-cb97c68e
```

That created a fixed disk for the instance in Amazon's Elastic Block Store.  Now I find I would like to upgrade to a large instance of EC2... but I would like to continue using the fixed disk I created for the small instance.

How do I switch it over?  (For the record, that AMI is for the US West Ubuntu image.)

Comment: I'm not sure whether stackoverflow or serverfault is the right site for this question; please migrate me if I'm in the wrong place!

Comment: This is a good place for it, though you may get better results asking on the official EC2 forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidentally, Eric Hammond has just written [an article](http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-change-type?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+alestic+%28Alestic.com+-+Ubuntu+on+EC2%29) about this exact topic. I think it should answer your question perfectly.